# Validation Blocking selecting files over 256 M Media Picker voyager laravel

Tags: laravel, voyager

When trying uploading Video file over 256 MB a javascript toast message  "File size too Big" appears, however, my php.ini file has  max_upload_size set to 3 GB

[image]

Comment: make sure you actually have that php config took effect, you can create a `phpinfo()` file and check the values there, secondly there's another value you migh want to update and that is `post_max_size`

Comment: Hi, Yes I check post_max_size is set  to  3GB as well, what's wried is if a change the media picker to an input file type the upload works

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to update both `file_upload_size` in addition to `max_file_upload` in your PHP configuration.

After updating, use `phpinfo()` to verify the changes are in place.

Comment: Hi, Yes I check file_upload_size  and max_file_upload  is set to 3GB as well, what's wried is if a change the media picker to an input file type the upload works

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is with dropzone-js it had a default max file size of   256 Mib